# 64 bit dll register

Tags: windows, dll, com, 64-bit, regsvr32

I have converted 32 bit COM dll into 64 bit dll by using x64 build.I tried to register
this 64 bit dll into 64 bit windows 2008 server uisng C:windows\system32 regsrv32.exe .But i'm getting an error message "Dllregister server failed  with error code 0x80029c4a".
How can i register this dll in 64 bit OS.

Answer (score 2):

That error code is `TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY` which likely means there was a call to [`LoadTypeLib()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221027.aspx) somewhere inside `DllRegisterServer()` and that call failed for whatever reason. A likely reason is the library was not added into the DLL resources.

Comment: i have that LoadtypeLib part in atlbase.h.but it was disabled form as #ifndef _ATL_DLL

Comment: @user443088: It's highly unlikely anything else would return that error code. You should try running regsvr32 under debugger and checking when exactly that error code is returned.